# What is causing Base Localization to create duplicate storyboard files?

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization, uistoryboard

I have an iPhone app that needs to be physically cleaned to prevent the following build error:

[image]

This is what I have in the Navigator:

[image]

And this is what I have in the Localization section of Build Settings:

[image]

It works, but I'm not sure this ever worked the way it was supposed to; it was written several (like 4) years ago.  Now, I am trying to clean it up so I can convert it to a universal app (first I need to make sure it works as designed before making any drastic changes.)

Can someone please point me in the right direction for cleaning this up? (I.e. what files to delete, or ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what probably happen in that project:

[image]

This `xx.lproj` file is a legacy. You should be able to find it in `Finder` but not in a `Project Navigator`. Like this:

[image]

This is only the internal structure of xcode so just **remove references from project navigator for all this ``xx.lproj` groups without removing files from project** and you'll be fine.

If the app stop building you may need to re-add this files to your target, to do this just select a "parent" storyboard and go to "File Inspector" (first tab on Utilities panel) and select desired target.

Comment: This is probably the best 100 points I have ever spent... thank you so much... works like a champ!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please award me with bounty whenever you can then :)

Comment: There was no indication that the bounty was paid... could you please verify that it was/wasn't paid?